# Ways to find out the active tab when multiple tabs are open inside a vue.js widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, coldfusion, axios

I am looking to list down all the possible ways to find out which tab is active when n number of tabs are open in a web browser. I would also like to determine when the tab is changed and when it went blur.

I have a vue.js widget on the page and i want the active tab information inside the vue widget. I can communicate to vue widget and pass in the information.

The webpage is coldfusion based and have access to jquery too.

I have a method inside the vue.js  widget that is called every minute and does a request that I only want to run if the current page is in the foreground, i.e. the user hasn't minimized the browser or switched to another tab. It serves no purpose if the user isn't looking at it and is potentially bandwidth and server intensive., so I don't want to just waste cycles in the background.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the specific widget that you're using? Might be easier to come up with a solution.

Comment: Please mention the widget library you are using. That can help us drill down the problem more. Also, try to provide code snippets or link us to the actual code in jsFiddle or codepen. :)

Comment: Can't you just listen to the `focus` and `blur` events on the window to keep track of the current tab's visibility?

Comment: I tried 
$(window).focus(function() {
         vm_alerts.$refs.displayAlert.startHeartBack();
 });
 
 $(window).blur(function() {
     vm_alerts.$refs.displayAlert.stopHeart();
 });
This doesn't work on all pages. it does not detect the focus and blur on all pages. It works on just a few. So i am looking for other options.

Comment: You need to add the above comment to the question. Also you need to describe how each tab gets activated. Lastly, I bet you are using a custom library as opposed to some 3rd party that has been debugged.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I don't think the solution has anything to do with ColdFusion. You need to determine from the front end (JavaScript) if certain conditions exist in order to then call some server based operation.

With [jQuery UI Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/), you can check which tab is active:

```
var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
```

If you're using someone's Vue.js Tabs component, you should ask them for documentation on how to select the active tab. Or you can post the code you're using to create the tabs in your question and someone might figure it out from that.

Comment: Thank you. I was using my own Vue.js component that i created.

Comment: I managed to pass the status of tab to the vue.js component from outside vue island and i used jquery to detect weather the tab is active or not.